# Store coordinates in associative array

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for a way to store data in VBS like

```
[ 0 => [posX, posY], 1 => [posX, posY] ]
```

Kinda an associative array with coordinates as values.

Comment: If I recall correctly (I haven't used VBScript for over 15 years) the closest data structure to associative arrays is the *dictionary*. However, your sample data looks like regular arrays :-?

Comment: which version of vbscript? That thing has 20 years of history, now..

Comment: @MarcusMüller C++ is 37 years old this year and still one of the most widely used production languages in existence, so what's your point? Age shouldn't be a determining factor, if they want to script with VBScript let them.

Comment: @Lankymart my point is that 1996's vbscript has little to do with ASP.NET vbscript. Also, pretty sure it's not 37 years old, already. VBScript appeared in the public around 1996. Also "one of the most widely used": yes, according to [TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/)  one of the 49 most widely used scripting languages. i.e. not that popular, if you consider it shipped with MS Windows for more than a decade.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I never said it was 37 years old, I said C++ was...as a comparison, re-read my comment. Also what does VBScript have to do with ASP.Net? Think you maybe confused, ASP.Net can use VB.Net not VBScript. If we are talking about server-side technology using VBScript then you mean ASP *(also now known as Classic ASP)*.

Comment: @Lankymart ooops yes, I misread that! sorry! My apologies. However, you misinterpreted my first comment: I really just asked OP to clarify which version of VBScript he'd be using – considering VBScript 5.5 isn't quite the same lang (or at least, you'd hopefully not write the same code) as 96's original VBScript. I *Thought* early versions of ASP.NET had a VBScript (not VB.NET) interpreter? Seems I was wrong.

Comment: @Lankymart also, of course, you're right, we should let OP use whatever language he likes – as obsolete as it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Associative arrays are called [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84)) in VBScript. You'd store coordinates in them like this:

```
Set coords = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
coords.Add 1, Array(1, 5)
coords.Add 2, Array(3, 2)

WScript.Echo coords(1)(1)  'ouput: 5
WScript.Echo coords(2)(0)  'ouput: 3
```

With that said, given your example you may want to create an array of dictionaries instead of a dictionary of arrays:

```
Sub AddCoordinates(ByRef list, posX, posY)
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  d.Add "posX", posX
  d.Add "posY", posX

  ReDim Preserve list(UBound(list)+1)
  Set list(UBound(list)) = d
End Sub

ReDim coords(-1)
AddCoordinates(coords, 1, 5)
AddCoordinates(coords, 3, 2)
...

WScript.Echo coords(0)("posY")  'ouput: 5
WScript.Echo coords(1)("posX")  'ouput: 3
```

An array of custom objects would be another option:

```
Class Point
  Private posX_
  Private posY_

  Public Property Get posX
    posX = posX_
  End Property
  Public Property Let posX(val)
    posX_ = val
  End Property

  Public Property Get posY
    posY = posY_
  End Property
  Public Property Let posY(val)
    posY_ = val
  End Property
End Class

Sub AddCoordinates(ByRef list, posX, posY)
  Set p = New Point
  p.posX = posX
  p.posY = posX

  ReDim Preserve list(UBound(list)+1)
  Set list(UBound(list)) = p
End Sub

ReDim coords(-1)
AddCoordinates(coords, 1, 5)
AddCoordinates(coords, 3, 2)
...

WScript.Echo coords(0).posY  'ouput: 5
WScript.Echo coords(1).posX  'ouput: 3
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot. One last question: is it possible to find the "nearest" element in a dictionary? For example I'm having coords at 0 and 100. If I get 75 I'd like to know the nearest coords (0 and 100 in this case). I want to interpolate missing coords, hence this would be incredibly useful.

Comment: You may want to post a new question with a little more explanation (and maybe some examples), because I fail to understand what you mean by "interpolate missing coordinates" here.

Comment: `Dictionary` isn't your only option, an `Array` inside an `Array` would also work. `coords = Array(Array(1, 5), Array(3, 2), ...)` you would then call it using ordinal like `posX = coords(1)(0)` would equal `3` in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, like this.
A dictionary is the key-value solution of vbscript.

```
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
objDictionary.Add 0, Array(1, 2)
objDictionary.Add 1, Array(3, 4)
WScript.Echo join(objDictionary.item(0)) '=>1 2'
```

Like others commented, vbscript isn't used much anymore.
Here an example in a more recent language like Ruby

```
hash = {}
hash[0] = [1, 2]
hash[1] = [3, 4]
# gives {0=>[1, 2], 1=>[3, 4]}
```

or as one line

```
Hash.new{}.merge(0 => [1, 2], 1 => [3, 4]) 
# gives {0=>[1, 2], 1=>[3, 4]}
```